# Nestjs 7 upgrade class-validator issue

Tags: node.js, typescript, validation, nestjs

We migrated out app to NestJS 7 version, after that all the class validations error just returns one type of error.

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request",
  "detail": "Bad Request Exception"
}
```

Before the upgrade it was throwing proper error messages for any class volitions. App boot level configuration is as follows. I have also upgraded the class-validator and class-transfoer packages to the latest.

```
 const validationPipeOptions: ValidationPipeOptions = {
        disableErrorMessages: false, 
        whitelist: true, 
        dismissDefaultMessages: false,
        forbidNonWhitelisted: false,
        forbidUnknownValues: true,
        skipMissingProperties: false,
        transform: true, 
    };
    app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe(validationPipeOptions));
```

Error before the upgrade

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Bad Request",
    "detail": [
        {
            "target": {
                "name": 4
            }
        },
        "value": 4,
        "property": "name",
        "constraints": {
            "isString": "name must be a string"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [migration guide](https://docs.nestjs.com/migration-guide#validation-errors-schema) from v6 to v7, if you like the old error message where it gave the details in the format above, you can set the `exceptionFactory` property to `excpetionFactory: (errors) => new BadRequestException(errors)`

Comment: I tried but still show only
```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Bad Request Exception"
}```